# "different" at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context

Is it correct to start a sentence with the word "different"?
for example:

> **Different table structures are listed below.**

or should it be:

> **Various table structures are listed below.**

Does it make any difference?

**EDIT:**
More context: I would like to point out and describe similarities and differences among several tables (there are more than 2 tables I would like to compare)

Comment: To answer your question: yes it is okay to do that. Your first example means '**alternative** table structures ...', and your second means '**a selection** of table structures ...'.

Comment: Different strokes for different folks.

Comment: (But what's a "structe"?)

Comment: Why somebody has down-voted this questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the lack of any other context, I would inturpet this sentence as:

> Table structures, that are different from each other, are listed below

So with that in mind I think your sentence is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Much depends on the *exact* context...

You'd be more likely to use ***different*** in a context where you've *already* presented one or more table structures (i.e. - where it means ***other***).

And you'd be more likely to use ***various*** where the table structures actually presented are a non-exhaustive list (i.e. - where it means ***some, a selection***).

Comment: FumbleFingers, could you please refer to the additional details that I added to my question?

Comment: If the context is that you're comparing a specific finite number of different table *structures* (which may be less than the number of actual tables referenced in your text, since some may have the *same* structure), it would be more idiomatic to introduce your list with ***The** different table structures are listed below*. Note that ***various*** is *not* suitable if you're presenting an exhaustive list like that (as opposed to just a selection or subset).